# javac file with dependency

Tags: java, javac

Sorry to ask a quite common question but I can't find a working answer.
I just want to compile using javac several source files organized like this:

- AdaptiveHuffmanCoding/

  - Encoder.java
  - Decoder.java
  - FullBinaryTree/

    - Node.java
    - Tree.java

For example, if I run

```
javac FullBinaryTree/Node.java
```

it works OK the class file is produced.

But if I run

```
javac FullBinaryTree/Tree.java
```

it will fail, reporting every Node appearance with an unknown symbol error.

As you can see the 2 files are in the same package so I'm not using any import and they are sharing the same 1st line namely

```
package AdaptiveHuffmanCoding.FullBinaryTree;
```

I guess I have to tell the compiler where to find this Node but I'm actually struggling with it. If someone could explain.

Thanks

Comment: yes, you have to configure `classpath` to tell compiler where to find other classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see the 2 files are in the same package...

To make classes of the same package accessible by the compiler, don't execute `javac` directly from this package but do it from the upper lever.

To compile the `Tree` class :

```
javac AdaptiveHuffmanCoding/FullBinaryTree/Tree.java
```

To compile all classes of this package :

```
javac AdaptiveHuffmanCoding/FullBinaryTree/*.java
```

Note that to be compliant with Java naming conventions : **packages should not contain any uppercase characters.**

Comment: Thanks.Now I have another error but it smells better.  Bad class file: ./AdaptiveHuffmanCoding/FullBinaryTree/Node.class class file contains wrong class: AdaptiveHuffman.FullBinaryTree.Node Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Comment: You are welcome Ben :) It seems that   `AdaptiveHuffmanCoding/FullBinaryTree/Node.class` should contain the `AdaptiveHuffmanCoding.FullBinaryTree.Node` class but it contains the `AdaptiveHuffman.FullBinaryTree.Node`  class.  `AdaptiveHuffman` differs from `AdaptiveHuffmanCoding` . Ensure that the packages and the directories be consistent.

Comment: OMG I must close the computer a bit and rest. Thanks again.

Comment: You are right as there is a time for each thing :) You are welcome again :)